# How do you draw small vertical lines on axis to delimit points instead of bullets?

Tags: tikz-pgf

So what I've got so far is this,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-3,0)--(3,0) node[below right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0)--(0,3) node[below right]{$V(x)$};

\draw (0,0)parabola(2,2.5);
\draw (0,0)parabola(-2,2.5);

\draw (-2.5,1.5)--(2.5,1.5) node[below right]{$E$};
\draw (-1.549, 0) node[below]{$-a$};
\draw (-1.549, 0) node{$\vert$};

\draw (0,0) node[below]{$(0,0)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which renders as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIt0z.png).

As you can see the vertical line near where it says -a is a bit too big, and I couldn't find a command that did the opposite of `\big`. So how could I draw a smaller verical line, to show that that is the point on the axis corresponding to $x=-a$?

P.S. I realise that I could draw a line using `\draw` but I would have thought there was a  more conventional way of doing it as with `$\bullet$` for bullets.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome! I would argue that `$\bullet$` should be replaced by `\draw circle`. That said, you can always try `node[rotate=90]{$-$}`. You might also look for the `pin` syntax.

Comment: Well the `rotate` feature seems to work, although it is a bit of a bodge. I'll have a look at the `pin` option as well. Thanks for the help. (If you want to put your comment as an answer, I can mark it correct.)

Comment: hm, people usually draw ticks: `\draw (-1.549, 1mm) -- ++ (0,-2mm) node[below]{$-a$};` by this it is on correct place and with desired size.

Comment: @Zarko Can you explain what the 1mm in (-1.549, 1mm), -- ++ and the 2mm in (0,-2mm) are supposed to do? I've had a play around with different numbers I can see the graph changing, but I'm not entirely sure what they do.

Comment: @GibbNotGibbs, the best way to learn what it do is test this code. Just us it to your image, and you will see :-) ... [ that it draw line from coordinate `(-1549,0.1)` (or `(-1.549,0.1)` ) below for 2mm and below this line write a label `$-a$`.] I suggest you to make yourself more familiar with `tikz` package. It has excellent (and huge) manul Ti*k*z & PGF Manula. For start read first tutorials and than part III: Ti*k*Z ist *kein* Zeichenprogramm.